# Different Materials appearing in Rendered View vs Preview View

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, 3d-view

in this model I originally applied different variations of a basic building material for a variety of objects. I later went back and changed the material of some of these objects as well as used Cube Unwrapping and the UV editor in order to change how some of the textures tiled. But for some reason, the changes I made later did not apply to the rendered view nor do they apply to the finished render.

[image: Here is the image of my preview viewport]

[image]

The first image is the preview viewport, which has a portion of the shot that is uv-wrapped correctly. The second shot is the render preview viewport, which has incorrect wrapping and mapping on some of the buildings. This occurs for more buildings throughout the camera shot. Included are some of the settings of the object and the render settings of the scene.
[image]
[image]

Edit: Here's a screenshot of my material node. The different building materials shown are all identical to this, with the only change being image file that is applied.
[image]

Edit 2: I wanted to have another screenshot of the problem. Here's one of the entire material differing from one viewport to another.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you do any baking or caching for this project?

Comment: I tried baking the project after the problem but it didn't solve anything.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your material node setups in question, or just state what nodes are being used?

Comment: Is is possible you scaled in object mode and forgot to apply the scale (Ctrl+A > Scale)?

Comment: I just tried applying the scale with Ctrl+A on the objects and it had no effect. I've also included the nodes onto the main comment.